# How do you find people to follow on Delicious?

Tags: delicious

It's possible to connect Twitter, Facebook and Google accounts on Delicious, but I haven't found a way to see a list of my contacts on those networks that are also on Delicious, even though the site says "Find more friends by connecting social networks to Delicious" at https://delicious.com/settings/friends

The [Network](https://delicious.com/network) link allows you to see links from your network but no way to add friends to your network.

Overall I don't see a way to add more people to my network except for knowing their username already.

Did I overlook something on the site itself?
Otherwise I'd also be happy with 3rd party solutions.